# Conditional Array output inserted into another Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, conditional-statements

I have following code which create an eemail campaign and send it to specific segments in mailchimp

```
    $data = array("recipients" => array(
        "list_id" => "$listId",
        "segment_opts" => array(
            'match' => 'any', // or 'all' or 'none'
            'conditions' => array (
                array(
                    'condition_type' => 'Interests', // note capital I
                    'field' => 'interests-0a6fa2c02e', // ID of interest category
                    'op' => 'interestcontains', // or interestcontainsall, interestcontainsnone
                    'value' => array (
                        '11111111',  // ID of interest in that category
                        '22222222', // ID of another interest in that category
                        '33333333',
                        '44444444',
                        '55555555'
                    )
                 )
            
              )
           )
        ),
        "type" => "regular",
        "status" => "paused",
        //"schedule_time" => $form_data['post_date'],
        "schedule_time" => "2020-09-15T15:00:00+00:00",
        "timewarp" => false,
        "batch_delivery" => array(
            "batch_delay" => 0,
            "batch_count" => 0
        ),
        "settings"  => array(
            "subject_line"  => $form_data['lbu_subject'],
            "title"         => $form_data['post_title'],
            "from_name"     => $form_data['lbu_from'],
            "reply_to"      => get_option('lubuvna-company-email'),
            "template_id"   => 999999,
        )
    );
```

I can get the dynamic values from the form like following, which is working just fine:

```
    if ( $form_data['lbu_to'] == 'multilists' && $form_data['lbu_multilistsvalue'] !== '' ){

        // get the comma separated values from 'lbu_multilistsvalue' input.
        $commaValues = $form_data['lbu_multilistsvalue'];
        $lubuvnaCommas = explode(',', $commaValues);

        $segment_opts = array(
            "segment_opts" => array(
                'match' => 'any', // or 'all' or 'none'
                'conditions' => array (
                    array(
                        'condition_type' => 'Interests', // note capital I
                        'field' => 'interests-0a6fa2c02e', // ID of interest category
                        'op' => 'interestcontains', // or interestcontainsall, interestcontainsnone
                        /*'value' => array (
                            '11111111',  // ID of interest in that category
                            '22222222', // ID of another interest in that category
                            '33333333',
                            '44444444',
                            '55555555'
                        )*/
                        'value' => $lubuvnaCommas // array from values
                    )
                
                  )
                )
        );

    } else {

      $segment_opts = '';

    }
```

The final structure should be like following, but this is not working:

```
    $data = array("recipients" => array(
           "list_id" => "$listId",
           $segment_opts,
        ),
        
        "type" => "regular",
        "status" => "paused",
        //"schedule_time" => $form_data['post_date'],
        "schedule_time" => "2020-09-15T15:00:00+00:00",
        "timewarp" => false,
        "batch_delivery" => array(
            "batch_delay" => 0,
            "batch_count" => 0
        ),
        "settings"  => array(
            "subject_line"  => $form_data['lbu_subject'],
            "title"         => $form_data['post_title'],
            "from_name"     => $form_data['lbu_from'],
            "reply_to"      => get_option('lubuvna-company-email'),
            "template_id"   => 99999,
        )
    );
```

I need to check if the 'lbu_multilistsvalue' is empty, then just avoide outputting the $segment_opts variable in the final structure. I always get stuck in such array where i need some data to be conditional..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_merge()` to combine two arrays.

```
$data = array("recipients" => array_merge(array("list_id" => "$listId"), $segment_opts),
              "type" => "regular",
              "status" => "paused",
              //"schedule_time" => $form_data['post_date'],
              "schedule_time" => "2020-09-15T15:00:00+00:00",
              "timewarp" => false,
              "batch_delivery" => array(
                  "batch_delay" => 0,
                  "batch_count" => 0
                  ),
              "settings"  => array(
                  "subject_line"  => $form_data['lbu_subject'],
                  "title"         => $form_data['post_title'],
                  "from_name"     => $form_data['lbu_from'],
                  "reply_to"      => get_option('lubuvna-company-email'),
                  "template_id"   => 99999,
                  )
    );
```

To make this work correctly, you should assign an empty array to `$segment_opts` when the condition is not true, not an empty string.

```
} else {
    $segment_opts = array();
}
```